# what actally reason of the specialization redefined

Tags: c++

For example

```
template<typename T,typename U>
struct Test{
}
int main(){
   Test<int,void> b;
}
template<>
struct Test<int,void>{

}
```

This code will cause compile error ,the error says "explicit specialization; 'specialization' has already been defined",we know duplicate explicit specializations are not allowed,So I guess Whether the complier generate the same code

```
template<>
struct Test<int,void>{

}
```

at the POI,and the same Code I defined after the main function,this is the reason of redefined explicit specializations?

Comment: That occurs because you provide a specialisation for a template that already has been instantiated from the default (even though the two don't differ – but they *might*). Move the specialisation before main and you should get rid of the error.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks,But if I define the code like ```template<typename T>
struct Test<T,void>{

}````,Then everything will be ok,By reason，It's also provide a specialization after Instantiation and should be have the same error

Comment: @jackX please dont put code in comments, instead you can edit the question to clarify it

Comment: @Aconcagua I'm sorry,even the partical specialization ,It also has the same problem,thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Would have been pretty surprised if not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the issue more obvious: Let's base template and specialisation *differ*:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Test
{
    T t;
    U u;
    void someFunction() { }
};

template<typename T>
struct Test<T, void> // partial specialisation this time - yes, possible, too...
{
    std::vector<T> t;
    double someTotallyDifferentFunction(std::string const&) const { }
};
```

Now any instantiation with second template parameter being void will have a vector, any other one will have the two members.

If you now, though, instantiate the base template *before* defining the specialisation, you get into trouble:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Test { /* as above */ };

Test<int, void> global_t;

template<typename T>
struct Test<T, void> { /* as above */ };
```

At the time `global_t` is declared, there exists only the base template. So it will be instantiated (in given case, this actually will fail to compile, though, as you cannot declare member variables (`u`!) of type `void`, but that's another issue, just let's ignore that for now).

Before instantiation, the compiler needs to specialise `Test<int, void>` *implicitly* (so one specialisation exists already). But *then* the compiler discovers the explicit specialisation – and this one conflicts with the previous implicit one.

Conclusion: you need to specialise *before* you instantiate...

Comment: The correct terminology would be: the implicit specialization `Test<int, void>` is instantiated :)

Comment: @Aconcagua  So,through the above explanation,The complier also generate specialization of Test<int, void> implicitely  when see the define Test<int,void> global_t,and the implicitely specialization conflicts with the explicite specialization which user defined ,and this is the reason why complied error

Comment: @jackX Exactly – the compiler cannot do anything else than implicitly specialising the base/default template as the explicit specialisation is not yet known at the time when `global_t` is declared.

Comment: @Aconcagua  OK,So the specialization the complier generated(implitely specialization) is not at the POI,may be in some other place of translate unit,and At the POI ,the generated code may be struct __Test__char { /* again same interface */ }; as you said before(logically，may be this code in memory) Is my understanding correct? thanks

Comment: @jackX Why the hell do you need a specialisation *'elsewhere'* and *another* class `__Test__char`??? A template specialisation, whether implicit or explicit, is just an ordinary class like any other class as well. Don't think about compiler internals (unless you want to build one yourself), that won't help you here. All you need to know is that the first time you instantiate a specific template, you create a new class. And you cannot re-specialise it differently, just like you cannot define one and the same class twice, such as `class C { int n; }; class C { double d; };`...

Comment: @Aconcagua what complex it is,Now,I'm  confused about what the process of complier to process the specific template,In my idea，for example ,Test<int,void> v ;the process is,First,match the best candidate template,obviously,here is primary template(here's no partial specailization template) ,Second,complier generate template<> struct Test<int,void>{/balabala/} for Test<int,void> ,then complier create instantiation from 'template<> struct Test<int,void>{/balabala/}' ,and lastly,the reuslt is just an ordinary  class you said,Is my understanding right,if it wrong,please point out my mistake

Comment: @jackX Imagine it as follows: The compiler has a lookup table for all classes, key is name, value is a set of information to the class (mainly size of objects to be created and some kind of lookup table for the functions translated). When encountering a name of a concrete class, normal or template instantiation as `Test<int, double> t;`, it will look up in the table if the class exists. If so, use it if not, then for normal classes fail, for template classes see if a template exists and can be instantiated (with base template or specialisations known *so far*). If not, fail, otherwise add ...

Comment: ... the newly created class (implicitly specialised/instantiated template) to the lookup table. Now we are back at the same point as if we had found the class in the table already before: `Test<int, double> t;` – the compiler now needs to reserve appropriate space for the object and make sure the constructor gets called; unless the constructor got inlined, this will just be an ordinary function call receiving the memory address of the reserved space as additional (hidden) parameter, which is what you see and can use as `this` pointer in the constructor (or any other member function later).

Comment: When the compiler now encounters a new *explicit* template specialisation (partial or full alike), it can look up all those keys in the table, if one matches the specialisation as well – the error you discovered already: Redefinition of an already (implicitly) specialised template...

Comment: @Aconcagua,Thanks very much for your wonderful answers,I get it,But last questions ,what is "implicitly specialised",we all know explicitly specialised as "template<> struct Test<int,double>{}" ,what's the form of "implicitly specialised"

Comment: The result of both is exactly the same, the difference is solely *how* you get them: the [explicit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explicit) ones you write *yourself*, the [implicit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implicit) ones you get *'from something else'* (the compiler generates them for you...). Remember that if you explicitly specialise yourself, the specialisation can look totally different to what the compiler would have generated from non-specialised template, see example in answer.

Comment: Interesting point about partial specialisations: You specialise explicitly, but only partially; full specialisations still need to be generated implicitly (by the compiler)...

Comment: @Aconcagua  I understand them, the newly created class has two processes,One is "implicitly specialised" (the complier generated specialization for me,due to I didn't write explicite specialization)，and the other is "instantiated template"(this process is the complier generated a ordinary class for  Test<int,double> ,In other words ,the actions like function name mangling,Make Test<int,double> like a common class such as Test_int_double_2 )

Comment: Why do you insist on two steps? As soon as you have a full(!) specialisation, you *have* that ordinary class already, no need to create another one from. Name mangling isn't standardised, though (it isn't even mandated, so if compiler finds another way to handle overloading, it can do so...), every compiler can do whatever it wants to, mangling might reveal that the class is derived from a template (most likely...) or it might not.